# 500 internal server error when using reverse-proxy

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have apache2 installed on my `Ubuntu 14.04 server`. In port 80 apache running while in `port 9000 nodeJs` app is running with forever. So I added to following lines to port 80 virtualhost 
in the apache2 config file to run nodeapp in port 80 using reverse-proxy. But now when I visit my site with port 80 I get and `error of 500`

```
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://128.199.136.209:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://128.199.136.209:9000/
```

The app runs well `in port 9000`. What is the error got this ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the necessary Apache modules?

Both mod_proxy and mode_proxy_http.